# git folder symlinks not recognized

Tags: git

I'm facing a problem with Git that persists despite extensive research. I have a master folder containing subfolders and files used across multiple projects (PHP). As I manage all my projects within a single workspace, I've previously linked individual subfolders of the master folder to the respective projects via hardlinks on Windows. For example:

```
Master
    Administrator
    Modules
        News
Project A
    Administrator (Hardlink from Master)
Project B
    Modules
        News (Hardlink from Master)
```

Now, I need to migrate my entire development environment to a Linux server (managed server by Hetzner). Unlike Windows, Linux doesn't support hardlinks for directories, only symlinks (ln -s) are possible. I replicated the project structure on my server as shown above and linked the respective folders as symlinks.

However, in Git, these linked folders are merely listed as files, and their contents are not recognized. I've already configured the following settings in Git:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = true
```

I assumed that setting `symlinks = true` would solve the issue, but Git still only recognizes a file, and the folder content remains invisible.

Can Git inherently not index or manage symlinks (directories)?
Is there an alternative approach I could consider?

Note: I don't have sudo access on the server and the git version is the latest 2.43.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Symbolic links are just files pointing to a given location. Therefore, git only track this file without resolving it (i.e., following the location stored in the link). This is a normal behavior. However, if you clone the repository, then you unix system should recognize it as a symbolic link and resolve it when needed.

Comment: Are you seeing the symlinks as files on Windows or on Linux or both?  What file system are you using in each case?